# React native - babel-plugin-module-resolver '1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm developing react native app with expo. But i have a problem. When i start the app with npm start or expo start. I'm getting this error.

```
node_modules\babel-plugin-module-resolver\lib\index.js:88
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

I deleted all node_modules. But it's not working. How can i fix?

node version: v8.11.4

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try reverting your current version of babel. I ran into this problem a while ago when there was problem in one of their dependencies

Comment: You're right. The problem is in other packages. I tried a different version of Expo. That's why it wasn't working.

Comment: The classic "I tried something else and it worked". Well what version worked for you?!